# How to get variable data passed from java class to native script jar file using javaScript

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

This is how I pass data

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("FingerPrint", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                            editor.putString("fingerImage", encodedWsq);
                            editor.apply();
```

And I want to access "fingerImage" data to my nativescript project, that is java files are exported to jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could directly use the [`application-settings`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) NativeScript module (which is using SharedPrefferences behind the scenes) to set & get the values.

TypeScript example

```
import { setString, getString } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";
setString("fingerImage", encodedWsq);
const myString = getString("fingerImage");
```

Comment: Sorry, for being late can you show the syntax for javascript